# Google-map-react - reactjs: How to dynamically show pop-up window after clicking on a marker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-map-react

I am building a boat visualizer using AISHub. I was able to locate the vessels I wanted using latitude/longitude and show them on a map. However there are too many vessel (markers) and I don't know who is who.

**The problem**: How do I show a pop-up window dynamically after clicking on a marker like below?

[image: marker]

Below the most important part of the code I am using:

```
class BoatMap extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buttonEnabled: true,
            buttonClickedAt: null,
            progress: 0,
            ships: [],
            type: 'All',
            shipTypes: [],
            activeShipTypes: [],
            logoMap: {}
        };
        this.updateRequest = this.updateRequest.bind(this);
        this.countDownInterval = null;
    }

// ... other operations
// ... other operations

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="google-map">
                <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'My_KEY' }}
                    center={{
                        lat: this.props.activeShip ? this.props.activeShip.latitude : 42.4,
                        lng: this.props.activeShip ? this.props.activeShip.longitude : -71.1
                    }}
                    zoom={8}
                >
                    {/* Rendering all the markers here */}
                    {this.state.ships.map((ship) => (
                        <Ship
                            ship={ship}
                            key={ship.CALLSIGN}
                            lat={ship.LATITUDE}
                            lng={ship.LONGITUDE}
                            logoMap={this.state.logoMap}
                        />
                    ))}

                    <select className="combo-companies" onClick={this.props.handleDropdownChange}>
                        <option value="All">All</option>

                        {this.state.shipTypes.map((type) => (
                            <option
                                className={this.state.activeShipTypes.includes(type) ? 'active' : ''}
                                key={type}
                                value={type}
                            >
                                {type}
                            </option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

1) I found [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271602/show-popup-on-marker-hover-mouseover-hide-on-mouseout-and-keep-open-on-click) which was useful to understand the procedure. But unfortunately I was not able to solve it.

2) Also I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335402/display-pop-up-information-on-clicking-marker-in-google-map) which is very useful, but there are two problems that are keeping me from using it: a) the info box is not dynamic, and b) I am using `google-map-react` but the post isn't:

3) Lastly I tried to write my own component `InfoWindowBox.js` and below is what I have done so far but have no idea if I am going in the right direction or not and if that should be implemented in the initial code:

**InfoWindowBox.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { InfoWindow } from 'google-maps-react';

export default class InfoWindowEx extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.infoWindowRef = React.createRef();
        this.contentElement = document.createElement(`div`);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.children !== prevProps.children) {
            ReactDOM.render(React.Children.only(this.props.children), this.contentElement);
            this.infoWindowRef.current.infowindow.setContent(this.contentElement);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <InfoWindow ref={this.infoWindowRef} {...this.props} />;
    }
}
```

Please is anyone has gone though this, guide to the right direction for solving it as I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this successfully in reactjs however I did not used google-map-react. I just plainly used some of the snippets from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57335720/11025839) and use it in my [sample react code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/marker-infowindow-8mnvwa?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Fmarker.js). You can see it in the link provided before you can see it work, you must change the API key in this line

```
const API_KEY = "CHANGE_YOUR_API_KEY";
```

For your reference, here is how I implemented it in my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var map;
var markers=[];
var infowindow;
const API_KEY = "CHANGE_YOUR_API_KEY" ;

class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.onScriptLoad = this.onScriptLoad.bind(this);
  }


  onScriptLoad() {
      var locations = [
            ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
            ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
            ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
            ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
            ['Maroubra BeachManly Beach Manly Beach Manly Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
        ];
      var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]),
            scrollwheel: true,
        };   
    map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.props.id), mapOptions);
    this.props.onMapLoad(map)

       for (var count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {
         var name = locations[count][0];
         var loc =  new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]);
            this.createMarker(name,loc);
        }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!window.google) {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=`+API_KEY+`&libraries=places,geometry`;
      script.id = 'googleMaps';
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      script.addEventListener('load', e => {
        this.onScriptLoad()
      })
    }
    else {
      this.onScriptLoad()
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036 },
      map: map
    });
  }

  createMarker(name,loc) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: loc,
      title: name

    });
    markers.push(marker);

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var content =
      'Location: ' + name +
      '<br/>Lat: ' + loc.lat() +
      '<br/>Long: ' + loc.lng() ;

    marker.addListener('click', ()=>{     
      infowindow.setContent(content);  
      infowindow.open(map, marker); 
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="root">
      <div className="map" id={this.props.id} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Map;
```

*Note: there are times that my code is showing 'google is not defined' error in Stackblitz, however you can still continue if you put a space anywhere.*

Comment: Pagemag, sample react code linked in the beggining of the answer is not working. [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/marker-infowindow-8mnvwa?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Fmarker.js) is the link.

Answer (score 6):

Best I can tell, there are 2 ways to add to Popups, neither is native to the `google-map-react` package (which recommends using react components on the map). You can position `<Popup />` either `position: absolute`, or by passing `lng` and `lat` to `<Popup />`.

**Step 1:** Create a standard `react` component, lets call it `<Popup />`.

**Step 2, Option A: Position with CSS**

Assign `position: absolute` to `<Popup />`.  This will allow you to avoid the math to determine when popup renders off-screen/outside viewport). Place the `<Popup />` adjacent to (sibling of) `<GoogleMapReact>`, and assign the parent container as `position: relative`.

```
<div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%', position: 'relative' }}>
  <GoogleMapReact
    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'SECRETS' }}
    defaultCenter={defaults.center}
    defaultZoom={defaults.zoom}
  >
    {markers.map((marker) => (
      <Marker
        key={marker.id}
        lat={marker.latitude}
        lng={marker.longitude}
        onClick={() => setPopupInfo(marker)}
      />
    ))}
  </GoogleMapReact>
  {popupInfo && (<Popup store={popupInfo} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, width: '200px' }} />)}
</div>
```

**Step 2, Option B: Position with map lat/lng**

Alternatively, you can pass `lat` and `lng` as props to `<Popup />`.  For this to work, `Popup` should be child of `<GoogleMapReact>`.

```
<div>
  <GoogleMapReact
    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'SECRETS' }}
    defaultCenter={defaults.center}
    defaultZoom={defaults.zoom}
  >
    {markers.map((marker) => (
      <Marker
        key={marker.id}
        lat={marker.latitude}
        lng={marker.longitude}
        onClick={() => setPopupInfo(marker)}
      />
    ))}
    {popupInfo && (<Popup
      store={popupInfo}
      lat={popupInfo.latitude}
      lng={popupInfo.longitude}
     />)}
  </GoogleMapReact>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for your time in reading the question, your time is very appreciated. This is also a very good answer.